# Migrating from ASA 5520 to 5525x

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall

what is the best way to migrate from Cisco ASA 5520 "ASA version 8.2(1)" firewall to **5525x**, iv'e tried to copy the running-config through the CLI and it went horribly " because of the deference in the NAT config and the VPN crypto maps. please advise. regards

Comment: What version are you running on the 5525x?

Comment: @RonTrunk 5525x minimum code version is 8.6, so I am imaging this is a question surrounding the NAT changes in 8.3+.

Comment: One way would be to copy the startup-config from the 5520 to the 5525x and reload it. It *should* run the conversion process, but don't expect to do a good job of it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco has a guide for migrating your ASA configuration file: [Cisco ASA 5500 Migration to Version 8.3](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa83/upgrading/migrating.html)

There are also online migration tools which you can find with a quick Google search. I haven't used any so I have no opinion of thm.